# Why I am not able to decrypt what I encrypted with pycrypto?

Tags: python, pycrypto

Here's my code:

Encrypt:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64

def encryption (privateInfo):
    BLOCK_SIZE = 16
    PADDING = '{'
    pad = lambda s: s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * PADDING
    EncodeAES = lambda c, s: base64.b64encode(c.encrypt(pad(s)))
    secret = 'Fr3@k1nP@ssw0rd.'
    print('encryption key:', secret)
    cipher = AES.new(secret)
    encoded = EncodeAES(cipher, privateInfo)
    print('Encrypted string:', encoded)

encryption('secret')
```

The encrypted string is: b'QuCzNmwiVaq1uendvX7P+g=='

Decrypt:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64

def decryption(encryptedString):
    PADDING = '{'
    DecodeAES = lambda c, e: c.decrypt(base64.b64decode(e)).rstrip(PADDING)
    key = 'Fr3@k1nP@ssw0rd.'
    cipher = AES.new(key)
    decoded = DecodeAES(cipher, encryptedString)
    print(decoded)

decryption("b'QuCzNmwiVaq1uendvX7P+g=='")
```

The result:

```
ValueError: Input strings must be a multiple of 16 in length
```

This is PyCrypto 2.6.1 on Python 3.4; I've installed VC++ 2010 Express as well.
What's really confusing me is that it works perfectly on Python 2.7

Any suggestion appreciated, but note that I'm new to Python.

Comment: Why do you need VC++ for this?

Comment: you have error in last line, should be: decryption("QuCzNmwiVaq1uendvX7P+g==")

Comment: I'm really not sure @linusg It seems that there might be some errors when installing pycrypto. It looks for Visual C++ files. It is VC++ 2010 after Python 3.3 so some people suggest to install it. I don't know what's the reason or weather it might have something to do after installation. Maybe it does, so I pointed that out.

Comment: I'm getting "TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface" @scope

Comment: @GlebG Ah OK, thanks for information. I think I used an installer for PY2.7, but I had problems with installing it on PY3.x too (I hadn't figured it out yet...).

Comment: Actually I wasn't able to install it any other way so I used an installer as well: https://github.com/axper/python3-pycrypto-windows-installer @linusg

Comment: Thanks! That did it!

Comment: It 'd be great to know if you're able to decrypt your encrypted strings @linusg Otherwise maybe there's something wrong with the installer so I'll have to install other 3.x Pythons to try to make pycrypto work on Python3.

Comment: I'll post an answer in a minute, I'm searching for the code I've written some time ago. BTW, please accept the edit I made to your question.

Comment: Sorry, I've found it, but it has problems running on PY3x... I'll try it tomorrow

Comment: **Never use [ECB mode](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14487/13022)**. It's deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. You should at the very least use a randomized mode like [CBC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22260/13022) or [CTR](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2378/13022). It is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research and a lot of coding, testing and improving, I made this code running on **Python 3.4.4** and **Windows 10**:

```
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256

PAD = "X"

def key_hash(key):
    return SHA256.new(key.encode()).digest()

def encrypt(text, key):
    while len(text) % 16 != 0:
        text += PAD
    cipher = AES.new(key_hash(key))
    encrypted = cipher.encrypt(text.encode())
    return base64.b64encode(encrypted).decode()

def decrypt(text, key):
    cipher = AES.new(key_hash(key))
    plain = cipher.decrypt(base64.b64decode(text))
    return plain.decode().rstrip(PAD)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    e = encrypt("This is my string.", "password")
    p = decrypt(e, "password")
    print("Encrypted:", e)
    print("Plain:", p)
```

**Output:**

```
Encrypted: QjkhFlXG2tklZQgHorpAOFSTb2vYZLNb/eEUIvAsT1g=
Plain: This is my string.
```

If you have any questions/improvements/critics, feel free to comment!

Comment: That works great! And it is a lot simpler than anything else I've tried on Python3 so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you have `"` around `"b'QuCzNmwiVaq1uendvX7P+g=='"`.

Change

`decryption("b'QuCzNmwiVaq1uendvX7P+g=='")`

to

`decryption(b'QuCzNmwiVaq1uendvX7P+g==')`

and you should be all set.

Comment: I'm getting: TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Comment: @GlebG It's pretty clear that there is a mismatch between str and bytes. The fix would be to add `.decode()` here: `c.decrypt(base64.b64decode(e)).decode().rstrip(PADDING)`. (@Vor feel free to include that in your answer.)